# Upper bound on polynomial over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, polynomials, field-theory

Consider a field $\mathcal{F}$ and any multivariate polynomial over $\mathcal{F}$ with indeterminate $x_1, ...,x_n$ and $a_0 = 0$ (the coefficient for zero degree), denoted by $f(x_1,...,x_n)$. In addition, assign a real-valued norm $||\bullet||$ for $\mathcal{F}$ (as a vector space over itself).

Given a real $r>0$, define 
$$
\mathcal{X}(r)= \{[x_1,...,x_n] \in \mathcal{B}^n(0,r)    \},
$$
where $\mathcal{B}$ denotes an open ball in $\mathcal{F}$.

Then for any non-zero $g \in \mathcal{F}$, does there always exists a real number $r_0>0$, such that

$$
||f(x_1,...,x_n)|| < ||g||,
$$
for any $[x_1,...,x_n]\in \mathcal{X}(r_0)$?

My *intuition* is that, by making $r$ sufficiently small for a given $g$, the above inequality should be obtainable.

Comment: this is true right? addition and multiplication are continuous, then $f$ is continuous, in particular continuous at $0$, which is the claim to be proved

Comment: We need to know something more about the field $\mathcal{F}$. You seem to assume that the norms have an ordering. Is the "norm" real-valued? I mean, do you lose something essential, is you state that $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\Bbb{C}$? Other than the abstract-algebra and field-theory tags, that is.

Comment: @jyriki: the norm is real-valued here. However, the field $F$ I have in mind is the field of rational functions actually. Let me re-phrase this question later.

Comment: @user757173: Thanks, that is an important hint that I can explore.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I think that it is trivial when $F \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ due to continuity?